# Invalid argument error while opening file in python

Tags: python, file-handling

code:

```
f=open("C:\\Users\Dell\assignment1\random_walk_tenk.dat","r")
```

I got the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Dell\x07ssignment1\random_walk_tenk.dat'
```

In this line, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try:  open(r"Users\Dell\assignment1\random_walk_tenk.dat","r")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward slashes needs to be escaped. Better way is to use raw string by suffixing string with r.

try:

```
with open(r"C:\\Users\Dell\assignment1\random_walk_tenk.dat") as f:
    data = f.read()
```

I do this insted.

```
from pathlib import Path

data = Path("C://Users/Dell/assignment1/random_walk_tenk.dat").read_text()
```

Comment: I searched on internet and found python has problem with back slashes so I tried forward slashes and it worked

Comment: See my edits for another way.

Comment: @Pirateking No, Python doesn't have a problem with backslashes. But there are programmers who don't know that a backslash is the escape character in a string definition in Python code.

Comment: I agree. It's window's probelm rather than python's.

Answer (score 1):

you can  add r string it will fix it  `r""`

```
f=open(r"C:\\Users\Dell\assignment1\random_walk_tenk.dat","r")
```